# Слетели стили сайта при переносе на хостинг

Tags: php, css, хостинг

Здравствуйте! Слетели стили сайта при переносе на хостинг. Не могу понять в чем причина. Пути к css файлам вроде прописаны правильно, но все равно стили отображаются не корректно. Сайт написан на чистом php, без всяких СMS и фреймов. На сервере все папки с файлами лежат в папке public_html. Добавлю скрин директорий сайта, что расположены на сервере. Стили у меня расположены в папке css, которая находиться в папке template. Хостинг называется **timeweb.ru**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как подключаю стили:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
        <title>List of employees</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link href="/template/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
```

Comment: `<link href="template/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">` пробовали?

Comment: Стили лучше прописывать полностью, с указанием домена.

Comment: Cheg, пробовала. Так вообще никаких стилей нет.

Comment: То есть мне прописать путь так: <link href="/employee.cd87421.tmweb.ru/template/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"> ?

Comment: @Visman вредный совет, потом будет куча проблем при попытке переехать на другой домен или поднять dev/staging окружение

Comment: @andreymal, если вы собираетесь прописывать домен в шаблонах, то я не виноват. У меня ссылки формируются на основании конфига, через метод :Р

Comment: @kittycat_13, добавьте содержимое своего .htaccess в вопрос.

Comment: @Visman а вот это полезный совет)

Comment: @Visman, добавила

Comment: Для проблем такого рода есть докер контейнеры, один раз положил код туда, при переносе все должно работать.

Comment: Сайт на чистом php? Случайно не GetSimple CMS использовался?

Answer (score 1):

При любых проблемах файлами стилей (или картинками, или любыми другими файлами, которые запрашивает браузер), надо сразу открывать **Инструменты разработчика** в браузере (F12), выбирать вкладку "Сеть" и смотреть, для каких файлов сервер вернул 404. Дальше надо брать полученный путь и смотреть, чем он отличается от реального.

Чаще всего проблема вызвана использованием [относительных путей](https://phpfaq.ru/newbie/paths) к файлам - то есть в каждой папке путь будет *разным*! Поэтому пути всегда должны быть абсолютными, от корня сайта.

Насколько я вижу, у вас сделано правильно, путь указывается абсолютный: `/template/css/main.css`. Если в папке template есть папка css, а в ней файл main.css, то он будет подключен на страницу.

Если же стиль не подключился, это значит, что такого файла там **нет**. Вам надо принять этот факт и начать разбираться, почему его там нет. К примеру, при заливке файл потерялся. Его надо просто найти и дозалить.

Фраза "после заливки на хостинг" может говорить о том, что имя файла пишется по-другому, с буквами в разном регистре, например Main.css или main.CSS. Для виндоус это без разницы, но в юниксе вы этот файл не найдете. И чтобы веб-сервер увидел этот файл, его надо просто переименовать. А лучше всего выбрать один стиль для имен файлов и всегда придерживаться только его.

Answer (score -1):

Можно создать константу (ROOT,dirname(**FILE**)) и подставлять ее вначале пути

Comment: константа `__FILE__` служит для файлов, и не имеет отношения к путям на сайте